# How can i get months in descending order in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to order the month wise sales descending in codeigniter and mysqli. Currently i am getting the data like this:

[image: Current messy order]

Please help me to order the months after checking the code too.

```
public function sale(){
    if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin') || $this->ion_auth->in_group('accounts')){
        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $this->load->view('partials/menu');
        $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count` ,SUM(`price`) as `price_count`,MONTHNAME(`created`) as `month_name` FROM `sales` WHERE YEAR(`created`) = '" . date('Y') . "'
                GROUP BY YEAR(`created`),MONTH(`created`) DESC"); 

            $record = $query->result();

            $output = [];
            foreach($record as $row) {
                $output[] = array(
                 'month_name'   => $row->month_name,
                 'count'  => floatval($row->count),
                 'price_count' => floatval($row->price_count),
                );
            }
        $data['output'] = ($output);
        $this->load->view('reports/sales', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        redirect(base_url().'404');
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your desired output order?

Comment: @Vickel i want the months in correct order whether these are asc or desc

Comment: Like this: February, April, May, June, July, August, Octuber

Comment: and how looks `created` like? is it a timestamp? here about [mysql Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Did you try to order by MONTH('created')?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query =  $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count` ,SUM(`price`) as `price_count`,MONTHNAME(`created`) as `month_name` FROM `sales` WHERE YEAR(`created`) = '" . date('Y') . "'
                GROUP BY YEAR(`created`),MONTH(`created`) ORDER BY created DESC");
```

Comment: No luck i am getting the order now Octuber,May,June,July,February,August, April

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the `created` column, and sorts by it :

```php
$query =  $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count` ,SUM(`price`) as `price_count`,MONTHNAME(`created`) as `month_name`, `created` FROM `sales` WHERE YEAR(`created`) = '" . date('Y') . "'
                GROUP BY YEAR(`created`),MONTH(`created`) ORDER BY created DESC");
```